# Can I change pages without losing the map

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, here-api, elm

I have a SPA and there are multiple pages, one of which is the MapPage. By opening the MapPage I am doing the normal map instantiating:

```
map = new H.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), defaultLayers.vector.normal.map, {..});
```

And here is the problem.
By going to some other page I am loosing the `'map-container'` html element and the domMarkers.

Is there a way of reusing the `'map-container'` html or I have to instantiate new `map` object every time? Or is there an option to redraw the map canvas?

Comment: Does the map display on every page? If so, then you could have a page wrapper that contains the map and only have the inner content of the page update on navigation.

Comment: No, the map is displayed only on one page.

Comment: Just to make sure I follow: You open a website where there is html element with `id="map-container"`, then you open e.g. `www.google.com` in the same browser tab and want to be able to access `#map-container` element?

Comment: @afv Did you try? Any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. In fact there are not many ways to achieve that, you have to keep the map container in the DOM, and the references to the map objects, otherwise they will be freed by the Garbage Collector.

It is more a Single Page Application problem, than something specific to HERE Maps API for JS.

This also means that you have to take care of hiding (`display: none;`) the map, on the pages where it is not expected to appear.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. But I am not sure why it worked though. All I had to do is to append the 'map-container' div from outside of the SPA framework(in this case Elm) before initializing the map. But selecting different (internal) page from within the SPA should have cleared the 'map-container' html. Maybe the Virtual DOM and the diffing process is the reason.